# How to get searching result in categories wise in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, full-text-search, search-keywords

I want to search any word and get the matched result as categories  wise to show them under different categories in column . How to get the quire code for search page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this solution for category wise search.

```
class Category_Wise_Search_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct(
            'category_wise_search', // Base ID
            'Category Wise Search', // Name
            array( 'classname' => 'widget_search','description' => __( 'A search form for your site with category', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
     extract( $args );
     $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
     $default_select_text  = strip_tags($instance['default_select_text']);
     if ( empty( $instance['default_select_text']))
     $default_select_text = 'Any Category';
     $show_count     = ! empty( $instance['count'] ) ? '1' : '0';
     $show_hierarchy = ! empty( $instance['show_hierarchy'] ) ? '1' : '0';
     $default_cat    = isset( $instance['default_cat'] ) ? absint( $instance['default_cat'] ) : 0;
     $exclude    = isset($instance['exclude'])?esc_attr($instance['exclude']):'';
     $exclude_t  = isset($instance['exclude_t'])?esc_attr($instance['exclude_t']):'';
     if(isset($_GET['cat']))
     $default_cat =absint($_GET['cat']);
     $cat_args = array('selected'=>$default_cat,'show_count' => $show_count, 'hierarchical' => $show_hierarchy,'show_option_all'=>$default_select_text,'echo'=>0,'id'=>'searchform_cat','exclude'=>$exclude,'exclude_tree'=>$exclude_t,'orderby'=>'name','order' => 'asc');
     ?>
     <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
     <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

     <?php       
       $form= '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    '.wp_dropdown_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_dropdown_args', $cat_args)).'
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
    echo apply_filters('get_search_form', $form);
    ?>


     <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
     <?php
     // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
    }
    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['default_select_text'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['default_select_text'] );
        if($instance['default_select_text']=='')
        $instance['default_select_text'] = 'Any Category';
        $instance['default_cat'] = ($new_instance['default_cat']);
        $instance['count'] = !empty($new_instance['count']) ? 1 : 0;
        $instance['show_hierarchy'] = !empty($new_instance['show_hierarchy']) ? 1 : 0;
        $instance['exclude'] = strip_tags($new_instance['exclude']);
        $instance['exclude_t'] = strip_tags($new_instance['exclude_t']);
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = $instance['title'];

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'default_select_text' ] ) ) {
      $default_select_text = $instance[ 'default_select_text' ];
     }
     else {
      $default_select_text = __( 'Any Category', 'text_domain' );
     }
     $count = isset($instance['count']) ? (bool) $instance['count'] :false;
     $show_hierarchy = isset( $instance['show_hierarchy'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_hierarchy'] : true;
     $default_cat    = isset($instance['default_cat'] ) ? absint($instance['default_cat']) : 0;
     $exclude    = isset($instance['exclude'] ) ? strip_tags($instance['exclude']) : '';
     $exclude_t  = isset($instance['exclude_t'] ) ? strip_tags($instance['exclude_t']) : '';
    ?>
     <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'default_select_text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Default select box text:' ); ?></label> 
       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'default_select_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'default_select_text' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $default_select_text); ?>" />
     </p>
     <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('exclude'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Exclude Categories :' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('exclude'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('exclude'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $exclude; ?>" />     
        <br>Enter a comma seperated category ID.<br>ex : <code>2,3</code> &nbsp;&nbsp;(This widget will display all of your categories except these categories).
     </p>
     <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('exclude_t'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Exclude Categories With Childs :' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('exclude_t'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('exclude_t'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $exclude_t; ?>" />       
        <br>Enter a comma seperated category ID.<br>ex : <code>1,4</code> &nbsp;&nbsp;(This widget will display all of your categories except these categories and its childs).
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'default_cat' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Default select category :' ); ?></label> 
       <?php $cat_arg = array( 'hierarchical' => 1,'selected'=>$default_cat,'show_option_all'=>($default_select_text!='')?esc_attr( $default_select_text):esc_attr( $default_select_text),'echo'=>0,'id'=>$this->get_field_id( 'default_cat' ),'name'=>$this->get_field_name( 'default_cat' ),'exclude'=>$exclude,'class'=>'widefat');
          echo wp_dropdown_categories($cat_arg);?>
     </p>    
     <p>
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_hierarchy ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_hierarchy' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_hierarchy' ); ?>" />
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_hierarchy' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show hierarchy' ); ?></label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>"<?php checked( $count ); ?> />
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show post counts' ); ?></label><br />
     </p>
     <?php 
    }
} // class Category_Wise_Search

// register Category_Wise_Search_Widget widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "Category_Wise_Search_Widget" );' ) );
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'shambhu_plugin_deactivate');

function shambhu_plugin_deactivate ()
{
 unregister_widget('Category_Wise_Search_Widget');
}
```